# repeatedly generates a random number from 0 to 30 until it reaches 200 or more in total

Tags: java, arrays

This random program should:

- repeatedly generates a random number from 0 to 30 until it reaches 200 or more in total.
- place each random value into an ArrayList number and prints the values in one line.
- set up an array of counters occurrences keep track of the occurrences of each possibility fills the array by examining numbers
- Print the likely values, with their occurrences, besides them in two columns.
- determine and print the most common number occurred in sentence form.

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or not and I don't know how to get the occurrences also on how to print the common one...Pleas help me.. My code is below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Random {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int counter = 0, num;
    int total = 0;
    do{
        num=(int) (Math.random()*30);
        System.out.print(num +" ");
        total+=num;
        numbers.add(num);
        for (int i=0;i<numbers.size();i++){
            if(i==num){
                counter++;
            }       
        }
    }while (total<=200);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" Numbers " +"   "+ "Occurences");
    System.out.println("  "+ num + "         "+ counter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `List` interface over the `ArrayList` concrete type. Second, generate the entire `List` before you try to count the occurrences. Something like

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
int total = 0;
do {
    int num = (int) (Math.random() * 30);
    System.out.print(num + " ");
    total += num;
    numbers.add(num);
} while (total <= 200);
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Numbers \t Occurences");
for (int num : numbers) {
    System.out.printf("%5d \t %5d%n", num, numbers.stream()
            .filter(x -> x.equals(num)).count());
}
```

You will need to determine the maximum count to fulfill the final bullet point.

Comment: I have posted 13 lines of code vs your 18. Mine **is** simpler. You could certainly replace the `stream()` and `filter()` with ***another*** loop - but that's up to you.

Comment: I mean another way of using the for loop and if-else statements.